# Executing TSQL script generated from SSMS in SQLCMD. Failing on quotes

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, sqlcmd, scripting

I am attempting to deploy a database to a machine by executing a script generated by the "Generate Scripts" tool in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is the command I've issued:

```
sqlcmd -S LOCALHOST\sqlexpress -I -U user -P ******** -i 
    C:\Rollouts\NI-9-25-2012_10-42-AM\Rollout.sql > rolloutlog.txt
```

I'm receiving errors like this:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 39488 near command ''' in file
>   'C:\Rollouts\ NI-9-25-2012_10-42-AM\Rollout.sql'.

When I view this line with a text editor all signs point to an issue with quotation marks.

The line in question looks like this:

> $(''.cat-menu-new'').slideDown(''slow'');

Is there a switch that I should be executing or generating the script with to support quotes within the script?

Comment: The script above looks like JQuery not SQL...???

Comment: Are you scripting out the data as well? Can you post any more of the script that was generated?

Comment: 40k+ line script? Ouch.

Comment: Haha to clarify a bit more. The script includes HTML and javascript content so yes that content is jQuery code. We ended up creating a backup script that is much faster and easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$(...)` denotes a variable in SQLCMD, so it's interpreting your data as a variable.

Use the `-x` [command-line option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to disable variables.

Comment: 11 years later and this answer is still helping frustrated developers :)